# Difference between Play F.Function.apply and regular lambda in Java

Tags: java, lambda, playframework

I have to fix some issues in code of a colleague who left, and thus I need to learn Play framework (version play_2.10-2.3.2) very fast.

What exactly is the difference between the two snippets of code below? Is it actually the same, or is there something I don't understand?

If there's a difference, when would you use snippet-1 and when snippet-2?

If there's no difference, why did Play Framework invent `F.Function.apply` when the same thing can easily be achieved with regular lambda expressions?

**snippet-1**

```
@Test
public void testObjectToObjectMqpWithApplyPromise() {
    Staff staff = new Staff("mkyong", 30, new BigDecimal(10000));
    F.Promise<Staff> staffPromise = F.Promise.pure(staff);

    F.Promise<StaffPublic> publicStaffPromise = staffPromise.map(new F.Function<Staff, StaffPublic>() {
        public StaffPublic apply(Staff o) {
            StaffPublic staffPublic = new StaffPublic();
            staffPublic.setName(staff.getName());
            staffPublic.setAge(staff.getAge());
            if ("mkyong".equals(staff.getName())) {
                staffPublic.setExtra("this field is for mkyong only!");
            }
            return staffPublic;
        }
    });
    System.out.println(publicStaffPromise.get(timeout));
}
```

**snippet-2**

```
@Test
public void testObjectToObjectMqpWithLambda() {
    Staff staff = new Staff("mkyong", 30, new BigDecimal(10000));
    F.Promise<Staff> staffPromise = F.Promise.pure(staff);

    F.Promise<StaffPublic> publicStaffPromise = staffPromise.map(internalStaff -> {
        StaffPublic staffPublic = new StaffPublic();
        staffPublic.setName(staff.getName());
        staffPublic.setAge(staff.getAge());
        if ("mkyong".equals(staff.getName())) {
            staffPublic.setExtra("this field is for mkyong only!");
        }
        return staffPublic;
    });
    System.out.println(publicStaffPromise.get(timeout));
}
```

Comment: Lambda functions are introduced later while play 2.0 is written earlier.

Comment: @Sam, so there's no reason anymore to use this F.Function apply() mechanism of the Play framework anymore?

Comment: yeah that's true.